# Java buttons: adding an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I have a superclass `Car`, and two classes that extend `Car` (`CarToRent`, and `CarToSell`)
In class `CarCompany` I implement a GUI in the constructor.

I have a button:

```
addCarToRentButton = new JButton("Add Car To Rent");
contentPane.add(addCarToRentButton);
addCarToRentButton.addActionListener(this);
```

How do I add an action listen to this so that when the button is clicked, it enters data from 3 text fields into an array of `Car` class? (the text fields are `dailyRateTextField`, `descriptionTextField` and `downPaymentTextField`).

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //action (someCar.setSomeValue(textField1.getText());

    }
});
```

Comment: The button already has an action listener, the `CarCompany` class.

Comment: Given the format by the OP it's hard to say, what is desired, so seems to me the answer is right in some angle, so removing the downvote, and easy way to respect, the intent to keep the encapsulation intact, by using this over what the OP has done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your `CarCompany` class implements `ActionListener` and therefore has a method;

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

}
```

When the button is clicked this method gets invoked. You might want to check that the source of the event is the `addCarToRentButton` and if so you can get the text from your fields, create a `Car` and put it in your array.

```
String rate = dailyRateTextField.getText();
String desc = descriptionTextField.getText();
String payment = downPaymentTextField.getText();

//Instantiate car

//add to array
```